# Pentaho/PDI: Increment a value automatically by one if a load-job (within a metajob) fails

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

**in PDI I've got the following structure**

- 0_Metajob
- 1_Load_1
- 1_Load_2
- 1_SimpleEvaluation
- 1_Mail

**As of now**
1_Load_1 and 1_Load_2 are independent of each other. The second one will run, irrespective of the success of the first one. That is okay, I want it that way!

**Issue**
I want to have a counter that is incremented by one every time one of the single loads fails, i.e. in my example the counter can take the values 0, 1 or 2.
What do I need it for? Customer will receive a mail at the end of the metajob. The aforementioned value determines the subject of the mail, i.e. 0=everything fine, 1=so-so, 2=load totally failed!
Why not mailing within every single the Load-Job? I do that but without attaching the log-file because it is usually non-finished. Therefore the log-file is mailed with the mail that is sent when the Metajob is finished.

**Tried**
"Set a variable". Thought I can simply increment it with adding a one in the value field, i.e. "${VariableName}+1". Of course, this step is implementened within a fail path of each Load-Job.
However, it didn't work.

Would anyone mind helping me? I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Set Variable doesn't do calculations, you'll need a Javascript step for that.

Fortunately, variables can be also be set within the Javascript step. This bit of code should go into each of the steps you put in place of the Set Variable steps:

```
var i = parseInt(parent_job.getVariable("Counter"),0);
i = i + 1;
parent_job.setVariable("Counter",i);
true;
```

This bit of code gets the variable "Counter" from the parent job and converts it to int, since all Pentaho variables are strings. Then it increments it and sets the job variable again. The "true" at the end is to ensure that the javascript step reports success to the main job.

IMPORTANT: This works roughly as you would expect in a Job. It will NOT in a transformation!